# assume different role in aws using java SDK on ec2 which uses assigned IAM for access

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Im running a simple Java application within a docker container on a EC2 instance. The java application itself has no hard coded credentials and the aws sdk assumes the credentials assigned to the EC2 instance.

This is working fine, but I now need it to dynamically assume a different role during mid execution. I'm trying to get the below code working to help do this but Im hitting an exception on the second last line "AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);"

```
    public void awsAssumeRole(String region,String roleARN, String roleName) {
        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();

        AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                .withRoleSessionName(roleName);
        AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
        Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();
}
```

Exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No AWS profile named 'default'
```

the variables Im passing through are in the below format:

```
roleARN=arn:aws:iam::account-id
roleName=role/role-name-with-path
```

I dont know how to specify a default profile as there are no credentials on the docker container running the application, there isnt even a .aws folder to put the configurations in, and I wouldnt be able to as we dont allow coding of credentials.

Is there a way I can implement role switching in my case?

Im running the application currently in intellij, using temporarily generated credentials which are passed through as environment variables in an attempt to replicate what the application would see during running in the docker container, but I dont know how accurate this is in terms of replicating how the app will run while in the docker container on the EC2 instance.

Im also very new to AWS roles, and role switching please forgive any misused terminology.

Many thanks

Comment: Should try with roleARN in full: `arn:aws:iam::account-id/role/role-name-with-path`. roleName can be whatever, e.g. `my-session`

Comment: @Marcin same error, i tried the below combination aswell and each returned the same error message

`arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name-with-path`
`arn:aws:iam::account-id/role/role-name-with-path`

Comment: So everything works with the app? It can access other AWS resources, e.g. s3. The only thing that does not work is assuming the new role?

Comment: @Marcin, Yes, it works, but only if i was to remove that above snippet of code which I introduced to try switching roles. Before attempting to tinker I had it working as expected in my IDE, it would automatically pickup the credentials from the environment variables.

Comment: `ProfileCredentialsProvider`gets credentials from the `.aws/credentials` file. I think you should use provider from the instance, e.g. `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider,` or container. Not too familiar with java-sdk by i see there are many providers [listed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html).

Comment: @Marcin, that was it! thankyou so much. I changed it to use `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()` while running in intellij, because my credentials are environment variables, so im assuming the `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` you provided will work within the container as its getting cred from the instance, Thankyou again!

also, I had the format for the roleARN incorrect, Ive switched it to `arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name`

Comment: Nice. If you don't mind, I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, there were two issues:

1. Incorrect format of `roleARN`. It should be full arn of the role.
2. Use of `ProfileCredentialsProvidergets` instead of `EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider`.